# Using Pandas to create a day/ night flag

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `bikes` with many columns, one of which is `ts` (datetime64). Format is `7/1/2015 00:00:03`.  I would like to create a `dayflag` column, which should indicate if the record belongs to the day or the night.

For the dayflag, I tried to adapt a solution provided to another date question I had posted.

`bikes['dayflag'] = bikes[(bikes.ts.dt.hour > 5) & (bikes.ts.dt.hour <18)]`, but I get a `Wrong number of items passed 18, placement implies 1` error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post full traceback with sample data

Comment: presumably you wanted to assign `True/False`? so something like `bikes['dayflag'] = np.where(bikes[(bikes.ts.dt.hour > 5) & (bikes.ts.dt.hour<18)], True, False)`

Comment: @EdChum, yes, the True/False would work. When I enter `bikes['dayflag'] = np.where(bikes[(bikes.ts.dt.hour > 5) & (bikes.ts.dt.hour<18)], True, False)`,  I'm presented with the following error: `Length of values does not match length of index`, which I Googled, but I still don't understand the nature of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to add a table to a column. Try to only assign the condition:

```
bikes['dayflag'] = (bikes.ts.dt.hour > 5) & (bikes.ts.dt.hour <18)
```